# Pandas Iterate Rows, Make Calculation, Print Time + Result

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time column and two columns with integers in a pandas dataframe:

```
time    data_01    data_02
01:00   5          2
02:00   7          3
```

I'd like to iterate over the rows and do a subtraction calculation (data_01 - data_02) and output the rows like below:

```
01:00 3
02:00 4
```

So far this is what I have so far:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    time = df['time']
    data = df['data_01'] - df['data_02']

print(time, data)
```

The problem is it outputs like this:

```
01:00
02:00
3
4
```

It would be great to write to a CSV file, but I'm getting a tuplet error. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: You can use `tuple` inside loop and add to a list may be? something like `list.append((time, data))`

Answer (score 0):

From your initial dataframe you can do something like this

```py
df['data'] = df['data_01'] - df['data_02']
df = df.drop(columns=['data_01', 'data_02'])
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

The .csv file is as follows

```
time,data
01:00,3
02:00,4
```